# Getting ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "env"

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to set up a manifest with specifying the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env variable:

```
kubectl version 1.18.10
```

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: $(appName)
  labels:
    app: $(appName)
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: $(appName)
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: $(appName)
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: $(appName)
          image: xxx.azurecr.io/xxx:$(Build.BuildId)
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
          env:
          - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
            value: Staging
```

However it's not working, validation tells me:

```
 ##[error]error: error validating "/home/vsts/work/_temp/Deployment_xxx6_1610541107518": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "env" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.Deployment; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I'm using Azure Devops Release Pipeline Powershell Task "Generate Kubernetes Manifest file".

Comment: Please add `kubectl version` and fix snippet formatting.

Comment: The indentation is exactly as it's shown in the question?  (That error implies `env:` isn't indented at all.)  This file isn't plain Kubernetes YAML syntax; how are you processing or submitting it?

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated intendation and formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Ok it must've been wrong formatting or indentation.
The following file is working now:

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: $(appName)
  labels:
    app: $(appName)
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: $(appName)
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: $(appName)
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: $(appName)
        image: xxx.azurecr.io/xxx:$(Build.BuildId)
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
          value: Staging
```

Comment: This worked for me. You can also try a kiss formatter like https://validkube.com/